# Menu in asp.net (not create)

Tags: asp.net, menu

My Menu is creating on **Site.Master** when I make to redirect on next page Menu create everytime. Wherein **Application** has a large load. I want optimization it. May I do it with session or other variant? Help me please.

Comment: Do you construct the menu by making a call to a SQL database?

Comment: @DenisWessels yes, but it is reusable procedure continuous data reading and menu rebuilding. I want to created menu the one time when I passed the identification.

Comment: Do a google search on caching techniques in asp.net